# Same function returning different outputs

Tags: php, datetime, date, strtotime

Well,this seems strange. Please bear with me. Someone asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756351/php-weekdays-of-current-week-why-is-date-and-strtotime-taking-next-week/11756424#11756424) question in SO. He wants the date of previous Monday. So i suggested

```
$monday=date(Y-m-d,strtotime('Monday this week'))
```

The output was perfect in my localhost. It showed `2012-07-30`. Another guy commented that the function i mentioned isn't working. It is giving the same date like

```
$monday=date(Y-m-d,strtotime('Monday'))
```

i.e., `2012-08-06`. And he isn't lying! The online editor which he linked is showing next monday's date. Check [this!](http://ideone.com/F6tOE) Why is this happening??

I searched, but couldn't get the reason behind it. Is it because of the older versions of php? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Somewhere between 5.2.17 and 5.3.10 the problem was fixed: http://viper-7.com/1PPz5m (look at the paste history). The changelog for `strtotime()` doesn't mention this (surprise surprise) but I know that there *were* changes to `strtotime()` for 5.3 so I'm guessing this is what fixed it.

Comment: OK, digging around in the [changelog for the 5.3.0 release](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0) I found this: `proper support for "this week", "previous week"/"last week" and "next week" phrases so that they actually mean the week and not a seven day period around the current day.` - sounds like that's probably the answer to me.

Comment: I've used strtotime('Last Monday') before and it was ok through several versions of PHP but worth checking if there is a specific version issue

Comment: @DaveRandom Yes i've seen it. I think it is same in the case of php 5.2.12. Am i wrong?

Comment: Well I read into that message that it was broken before 5.3.0 - so in 5.2.12 it won't work right. Your version is giving you the right answer, ideone is giving you the wrong one because it's running a very old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere between 5.2.17 and 5.3.10 the problem was fixed: http://viper-7.com/1PPz5m (look at the paste history).

Digging around in the [changelog for the 5.3.0 release](http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.3.0) I found this:

> proper support for "this week", "previous week"/"last week" and "next week" phrases so that they actually mean the week and not a seven day period around the current day.

Sounds like that's probably the answer to me. Basically before 5.3.0 `this week` etc may give you the wrong answer, because it will look for the day in the 7 days surrounding the current date that is a Monday, whereas in 5.3.0 and later it will be interpreted correctly.